# update specific child object in knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I've a nested objects like:

```
Album
-- Track 1
----Clip
--Track 2
----(None)
Album
--Track x
----Clip
```

i've created viewModel using knockout mapping plugin. Everything is working as expected (in fact with help of this thread [can't resolve knockout js with nested objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418740/cant-resolve-knockout-js-with-nested-objects))

Now the problem is Clip object for Track 2 does not exist initially. In the interface, user created it and i got proper JSON from server (ajax call) about this clip object. Now, how can I update my viewModel (viewModel.albums is the mapped object) to push this Clip info to Track 2 from my Ajax callback? I do not have any clue about the context of the Track from the ajax callback. If I had, it would be easier, I think.

If the question does not make sense, I will try to put something more visual in jsfiddle. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
viewModel.albums()[i].tracks()[j].clip = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
```

In which *i* is which album you want to push it to and *j* is which track in that album you want to push it to.

Comment: thanks but it is not possible as i do not have album/track data in this context. i got a solution using `contextFor/dataFor` but problem is that DOM is not updating properly though the new values are reflected nicely in the viewmodel. I stored the element in a contextElement variable. Then `track = ko.dataFor(contextElement)
track.clip = ko.mapping.fromJS(data)`! `obj_viewmodel.albums()[1].tracks()[1].clip` gives me correct value but not reflected in dom