# knockoutjs mapping custom objects with nesting array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-2.0

i want to map this json to custom objects.
The problem is that items are not typeof Item object but normal Objects.
What I'm missing here?

You can test here: http://jsfiddle.net/5jhpE/

```
var json = [
    {
        id: 1,
        items: [
            {id: 1, name: 'item1'},
            {id: 2, name: 'item2'},
            {id: 3, name: 'item3'}
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        items: [
            {id: 4, name: 'item4'},
            {id: 5, name: 'item5'},
            {id: 6, name: 'item6'}
        ]
    },
]

function Data(data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
}

function Item(data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
}
var map = {
    create: function(options) {
        return new Data(options.data);
    },
    items: function(options) {
        return new Item(options.data);
    },
}

var res = ko.mapping.fromJS(json, map);
```

Output:

```
console.log(res());
[Data, Data]
--
console.log(res()[0].items());
[Object, Object, Object] <-- Here I want to have [Item, Item, Item]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've changed your mapper options in this way

```
var map = {
    'items': {
        create: function(options) {
            return new Item(options.data);
        }
    }
}
```

and seems fine;
Could you try?

If you need: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fpezzato/KHHYD/)
the console output is *[Item, Item, Item]* as you want;

---

I permit to add one little suggestion: if you need to test the typeof in this way:

```
typeof res()[0].items()[0]
```

pay attention, it could be tricky!

To avoid any problem, I usually declare the Item viewModel  in this way:

```
function Item(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.myType = 'item';
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
}
```

so you can simply test, for example :

```
if('item' === res()[0].items()[0].myType) {
  //do something...
}
```

*This "myType" trick was suggests here in stackoverflow some time ago: I'll post the link here as soon I'll find the post*

Comment: doh!! Tnx a lot mate! I was very tired and I missed `create`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this question: [Map JSON data to Knockout observableArray with specific view model type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951521/map-json-data-to-knockout-observablearray-with-specific-view-model-type)

It maps custom nested objects and also contains a fiddle that does so.