# How to add JSON data to an observableArray

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mapping-plugin

In the html page i have a view model

```
 AppViewModel = {
        people : ko.observableArray([
        {
            fName : 'john'
            lName :'conor'
        }, {
            city  : 'dallas'
        }, {
            state : 'texas'
        } ]),


    };
```

and i fetch the json data from the server in the format

```
{
                fName : 'john'
                lName :'conor'
            }, {
                city  : 'dallas'
            }, {
                state : 'texas'
            }
```

i want the json data to get added to the array(push), anything like AppViewModel.people.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(jsondata, viewModel))
but it is not working.
 Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Map JSON data to Knockout observableArray with specific view model type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951521/map-json-data-to-knockout-observablearray-with-specific-view-model-type)

Comment: why ko.mapping.fromJS  is not working?? please post a jsfiddle example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If jsonData is an array, this works.

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(jsondata, function(item){
    AppViewModel.people.push(item);
});
```

**Edit**

You can check if the object is not empty by using [jQuery.isEmptyObject](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/).

```
if(jQuery.isEmptyObject(jsonData) == false)
    AppViewModel.people.push(jsonData)
```

Or you can use this version of isEmpty :

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
    for(var prop in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks,how to set the property value when the jsondata is not an array and it may be empty pls help

Comment: If it is not an array, what it is ?

Comment: sometimes the jsondata is like {"lName":"john","fName":"conor"} and {}

Comment: So, if jsonData is empty you don't want to alter the people array, but when jsonData is an object with properties you want add it to the people array ?