# How to add extender to existing observable in Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've looked at this:
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html

**The issue is that I'm using fromJs to create my view model, so my observerables already exist. I would think I could do the following to add an extender:**

```
var data = result.Data;
if (!window.vmRealTimeActivity) {
    window.vmRealTimeActivity = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mappingKeys);
    ko.applyBindings(vmRealTimeActivity, $('#second-btm')[0]);
} else {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, vmRealTimeActivity);
}

vmRealTimeActivity.MyExistingObservable.extend({ numeric: null });
vmRealTimeActivity.MyExistingObservable(9999);  // doesn't call numeric extender
```

My extender gets called the first time the extender is attached, but not after trying to change the value.

**I read another SO post that stated that .extend() creates a new observerable so you have to do this, but this doesn't work either:**

```
vmRealTimeActivity.MyExistingObservable = vmRealTimeActivity.MyExistingObservable.extend({ numeric: null });
```

In addition to not calling my formatter a second time, the value starts coming back NaN.

**How do I attach an extender the proper way to an existing observable?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the mapping plugin, you could specify a `create` callback. If you add the following to the existing mappingKeys, it would probably work (I don't know your exact mapping, so you might need to change bits here and there):

```
'MyExistingObservable': {
    create: function(options) {
        return new ko.observable(options.data).extend({ numeric: null });
    }
}
```

This result in an extended observable upon mapping from yor data.

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ufKL7/2/) with a working example (vm1) and your current non-working example (vm2) for comparison

Comment: Thanks! How would this apply to an observable array? Previously I was doing this: $.each(vmRealTimeActivity.Goals(), function (i, e) {
                                e.Count.extend({ numeric: null });
                            });  >> So I could extend the Count property of the Goals collection that gets automatically generated. I tried something like this:  create: function (options) {
                var newArray = ko.observableArray(options.data);  >> Based on your code but no luck.

Comment: [Just to illustrate how you could this with an observable array](http://jsfiddle.net/KrP9D/). There's lots of room for improvement there, but I just wanted to make a quick example. Instead of returning  new observables in the 'create' callback, you could return a new viewmodel as well. Just have a look at the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) for the mapping plugin, the section called **Customizing object construction using “create”**

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. It's ironic, because I had created the view models manually before and I switched to using fromJs, which seems to be more work than it's worth. lol

Comment: Sorry to trouble you one last time. I've realized I need to just define the viewmodel and use from JS to refresh it. But, I see no way to get the extend to apply since it's in a child view model and fromJs knows nothing about it. I'm thinking there must be some way to map the child view model when using fromJs? I've made an example so you can see: http://jsfiddle.net/KrP9D/3/

Comment: Nm, i found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951521/map-json-data-to-knockout-observablearray-with-specific-view-model-type

Comment: @KingOfHypocrites, +1 for actively searching your own solutions, I wish more SO users would be that proactive.

Comment: How would this be possible without using the mapping plugin? E.g. new mapExample(); ... and ... var mapExample = function() { this.myObservable = ko.observable(); }

Comment: @RonaldHulshof Did you ever find this answer? I am in need of extending an existing observable without the use of the mapping plugin. I am unable to find anything useful :(

Comment: @WebDevNewbie I ended up using a good old if/else construction. One with the extender, one without. So no, I didn't actually find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct, but for anyone interested, I found the simpler approach is to just create your view models client side and use fromJs to refresh them rather than both create and refresh them. You can then apply the answer here to support adding extend to both your parent and child view models: [Map JSON data to Knockout observableArray with specific view model type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951521/map-json-data-to-knockout-observablearray-with-specific-view-model-type)

With either approach you will have to create additional mappings.